# Joining more than 2 streams using the same sliding window in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 3 streams A, B and C that I am supposed to join into a single stream lets call it ABC and do some operation on.

It is important that I use sliding windows with size X and slide Y where Y <= X*3

**All the streams contain some common ID that I use for the join and X, Y are time parameters defined in seconds.**

My current implementation is to join stream A and B into AB using a tumbling window of with size X and then join AB with C using a sliding window with size X and slide Y.

This may lead to incorrect answers in cases such as: Stream A receives a message at time 0, and Stream B receives a message at time Y+1. In this case both messages **should** go inside the same sliding window because Y+1 < X, but the end result is that when I join AB and C the message from B is missing due to the initial tumbling window.

Can I do a multi-stream join in Flink using a single sliding window similar to how I would do join multiple dataframes in Spark?

Comment: I don't understand your scenario. Suppose X=60 and Y=20. Stream A has a message at time 0, and stream B has a message at time 61. 61 is not less than 20, and there is no window that should contain these two messages. Having X+1 be less than Y means that X is less than Y, which is a strange way to have a sliding window.

Comment: @DavidAnderson You are right, I mixed X and Y in my text. Suppose X = 15 and Y = 5. If A has a message at time 0 and B has a message at time 6, they should be part of the same sliding window, just at different intervals

Comment: That should work, though you may need to assign timestamps and watermarks again after the tumbling join window.

Comment: But I cannot join more than 2 streams at a time without applying a window function. I.e If I cannot do A.join(B).where(..).equalTo(..).join(C).where(..).equalTo(..).window(SlidingEventWindow), I have to do: A.join(B).where(..).equalTo(..).window(..).apply(..).join(C)..where(..).equalTo(..).window(..).apply(..);
So if I want the output to be a sliding window of the 3 streams should I first apply a slidingwindow(X, Y) THEN a tumblingwindow(X)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Could you provide an example of how you would join 3 streams in the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what will work in this case is to use two sliding window joins -- one to compute AB, and another to join those results with C. The one issue you may have is with the timestamps on the records produced by the first join -- I'm not sure what timestamps Flink will put into the StreamRecords that wrap your AB events, but for normal (non-join) windows, Flink sets the timestamps on the result records to the window end time. This may not be what you want in this case. If this is an issue, you can put an additional timestamp assigner after the first sliding window to set the timestamps appropriately, before the second join (with C).